# More elegant way of replacing substring of text that was matched with regex

Tags: python, python-regex

I am new to python so I would like to get a few ideas for this.
I am writing a function to find matching word patterns in a sentence and replace the spaces inside of only the matched words.

**Input:**

> (c)variable ＜ var_CONST1(例 -125(N)) 【AAA BBB有】AND【技術企画】AND【AAA BBB CCC】

**Expected Output:**

> (c)variable ＜ var_CONST1(例 -125(N)) 【AAA-BBB有】AND【技術企画】AND 【AAA-BBB-CCC】

In the sample, spaces inside "【AAA BBB有】" and "【AAA BBB CCC】" should be replaced with "-".

I created the code below which solves the problem. However, I would like to know if is a better/more elegant way of writing it.

```
import re

text = "(c)variable ＜ var_CONST1(例 -125(N)) 【AAA BBB有】AND【技術企画】AND 【AAA BBB CCC】"

match_list = re.findall(r"【[\w\s]+】", text)
match_list = [w.replace(" ", "-") for w in match_list]
tmp_txt = re.sub(r"【[\w\s]+】",  " tkn ", text).split()

new_txt = ""
for txt in tmp_txt:
    if txt == "tkn":
      new_txt = new_txt + " " + match_list[0]
      match_list.pop(0)
    else:
      new_txt = new_txt + " " + txt

print(new_txt)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `re.sub` here with a callback function to target only spaces occurring inside `【...】`:

```py
inp = "(c)variable ＜ var_CONST1(例 -125(N)) 【AAA BBB有】AND【技術企画】AND【AAA BBB CCC】"
output = re.sub(r'【.*?】', lambda m: m.group().replace(' ', '-'), inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
(c)variable ＜ var_CONST1(例 -125(N)) 【AAA-BBB有】AND【技術企画】AND【AAA-BBB-CCC】
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that lambda expressions are a thing (we don't really use it in our projects made in VB).
Also, it was my first time seeing groups() so I made a quick search and arrived to this site: https://pynative.com/python/regex/.
Do you think the contents are enough for learning python regex?

Comment: You can simplify even more: `re.sub(r'(【\w+)\s+(?=.*?】)', '\\1-', text)`
Unfortunately Pythons regex backward looking capabilities are limited to fixed length strings but you can do it without a lambda function using the lookahead and lookbehind feature of regex.

Comment: @Ronny No, that doesn't work, [as this demo shows](https://rextester.com/ZZFF38637).

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was wrong. Missed the last dash and there's no `suball()`, will not work like this unless one uses more advanced regex machine like https://pypi.org/project/regex/
Then you can do: `import regex as re` and `e.sub(r'(?<=【.*?)\s(?=.*?】)', '-', text)`

Comment: ...the other problem with your attempt is that it assumes that the content inside brackets has a known format.  My answer does not make this assumption, and will replace all spaces with dash regardless of content.

Comment: Yes, because the builtin Python re module does not allow flexible backward looking. The regex package on pypi allows this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have a quick confirmation. I tried using `r"【.*?】"` instead of `r"【(.*?)】"` and it seems to arrive to the same result. My understanding is that `()` is used to capture a group. What is the difference of using group and what are the advantages?

Comment: @Spitfire You're right, and we don't need that capture group in this case.  Good catch!